# "Adjoin" vs "join"?

Tags: word-meaning

Is there significant difference between the words `"adjoin"` and `"join"`?

The words seem related and are close in meaning. How do the meanings relate to each other? I would like to look at examples where these words mean something slightly different.

Comment: I've voted to close this as a "dictionary lookup" question. If you had included definitions and/or examples of each word, and explained _why_ you were still confused, then that would be a worthy question.

Comment: *Join* is about a thousand times more common.  *Adjoin* is relatively uncommon, although the separate word *adjoining* (an adjective derived from *adjoin*) is a bit more common than *adjoin* itself.

Comment: The most common use by far of *adjoining* is with a following word describing a room or other physical space: *adjoining room, adjoining bathroom, adjoining bedroom, adjoining land, adjoining area, adjoining property*, and so on.

Comment: (Sorry, I can't post an answer since it was closed as off-topic.)

Comment: @snailboat I assume it was you that voted to reopen? It helps with reopen votes if you explain in a comment why you think the close reason doesn't hold for the question you're voting on. I always read the comments when close/reopen voting, in case another reviewer thought of something I didn't think of.

Comment: I’m voting to re-open on the grounds that it’s a passable question as-is and has garnered a decent answer already. There’s still a lot of room for improvement if OP could add detail around current understanding and remaining confusion. These two words have different definitions and usage examples in dictionaries, so we need to understand more about what brings you to ask this question if we are going to give a better answer than you can find by comparing [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjoin) to [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Adjoin` is usually used to describe properties or places -- something physical -- whereas join can be used of pretty much anything ("joining ideas", "joining together in chant", etc.)

`Adjoin` is most often used as an adjective, such as in the sentence `The adjoining room in the hotel...`.

`"In the joining room"` wouldn't have the same meaning and would probably be considered incorrect.